# Entity Framework can't migrate MaxLength value when column has index

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I try to change MaxLength property from 100 to 50 and i got exception that Says

```
"The index 'IX_Singers_Name' is dependent on column 'Name'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Name failed because one or more objects access this column."
```

Mode is :

```
public class Singer : NamedEntity
{
    [MaxLength(50)] // It was 100
    public override string Name { get; set; }

}
```

As i understand, entity framework needs to alter table for this change but it can't alter table because an index exist on Name property. So how i can make it possible with entity framework migrations ?

I can possibly drop index in migration then change maxlength in next migration and create index the last migration again. But i believe that there should be exist an easy way to change that attribute value.

Comment: how was the index created? also it's not clear to me if you want to change both or just value of the attribute (I don't think the latter is possible since this is what code first uses to build the database and to validate that your model matches the database)

Comment: Indexes are created via migrations.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, indexes are pretty much like tables themselves. So if you've got the column in an index, both that index and the table would need to be modified. I agree that where EF migrations were scaffolded to add the index (e.g. for a foreign key) they should also take care of removing and reapplying the index. However, in this instance the index would have had to have been added manually. Therefore it will need to be maintained manually in the migration. Note that it can be done in a single migration:

```
public override void Up() 
{
    DropIndex("dbo.Singer", new []{"Name"});

    /* Code to alter the table */

    CreateIndex("dbo.Singer", "Name");
}
```

Don't forget to put this in both the `Up()` and `Down()` methods.